# Unity: Set Game to animation frame rate, Why Not?

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, animation

The animation in my 2D game is 24FPS. Is there any good reason not to set the game's target frame rate to 24FPS? Wouldn't that increase performance consistency and increase battery life on mobile? What would I be giving up?

Comment: Yes, there is a good reason: it gets slow. Just change your animation speed to match the correct speed (24) and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write nothing about the kind of game, but I will try to answer anyway.

Setting 24 FPS would indeed increase performance consistency and battery life.
The downside is, besides getting laggy visuals, an increased input lag. That will not only effect the 3D controls but also every UI-Button. Your game will feel a bit more laggy than other games, a very subtile feeling that will sum up after a while.

You could get away with 24, depending on the nature of your game, you should test it with different people. Some are more sensitive to that issue than others.

If you set up the animations to have their correct framerate, Unity will interpolate the animation to the games framerate. So there is no need to have the same values on animations and the game itself.